# Difference between 'man ls' and 'ls --help'?

Tags: linux, shell

I use both `man` and `--help` in Bash programming to get help.
For example, to get information about usage of `ls` command, I may use

```
man ls
```

Or

```
ls --help
```

Both give some what similar output. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one, `--help` is not a command, it is an argument that is often given *to* a command to get help using it. Meanwhile, `man` *is* a command, short for "manual". Manual pages are installed by many programs, and are a common way to find help about commands, as well as system calls, (e.g. `fork()`).

If a program installs a manual page, it can always be accessed via the `man` command, whereas `--help` is just a common convention, but need not be enforced—it could be just (and only) `-h`.

`man` also typically uses a pager, such as `less`, automatically, which can make viewing and searching through the information much easier.

Finally, you mention Bash programming in your question—none of this is unique to Bash. Bash doesn't care about the commands themselves or their arguments for the most part.

Comment: To find out which document ``man`` will show you for ``ls`` you can type ``man -w ls``

Comment: @holygeek awesome, I didn't know that, actually.

Comment: I seldom do ``man man``, but when I do, I always learn new stuff from it :)

Comment: @holygeek Do you happen to know how to find the names of each manual section from the terminal? I feel like I used to know and now it's escaping me and I can't find it in `man man`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "names of each manual section".  I'm guessing you want something like ``man foo|grep '^[A-Z]'`` (for that I don't know the command line switch that does it directly too)? or maybe ``man -wa foo``?

Comment: @holygeek [This is what I mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections). I also forget which is system calls, libraries, etc. I'm probably getting a bit carried away for a comment, though.

Comment: On some systems, `man man` lists the names of the manual sections.

Answer (score 4):

In most scenarios `man` is more detailed than `--help`. `help` gives the command line options for a particular command. But `man` is a lot more detailed.

Plus `man` is a command-line tool in itself whereas `--help` is a command-line arg for a tool. Small difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the first you asking the system to search the manual pages for help on the command. The second you are asking the command to provide its own help. The two will most certainly differ - usually the command provides a reminder of its options where as the man page is a detailed description.

Comment: While there is no guarantee that *any* documentation is correct, at least with `--help` you know that you are getting the help message *from the program that you want to run*. Man pages can get out of sync with `/bin` and so can refer to software versions different from what's actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

`man some_command` is something you can expect to work on all Unix and Unix like OSes, unless the manual pages are not installed.

`some_command --help` is mostly a GNUism so it generally won't work with non GNU implementations.

GNU, which doesn't like manual pages for some reason, also introduced `info some_command` as third alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I find `--help` useful as it lets me call help up while I'm modding a command

For example

```
rsync -vPn ./* ./newfolder/.
```

*Oh -- What is the flag for compress?*

```
rsync -vPn --help ./* ./newfolder/. | less
```

I find the help command on flags sometimes very very useful and less time consuming. With man I've got to type it in and the go back through my history to get back to the command I was in.